# How can I download a file in c++ with parameters not using libcurl

Tags: c++, file, download

so I have a question on how to download a file off my site using parameters in c++ example: "test.com/test.php?user=name&token=sgdashg"
I can't seem to figure out how I tried UrlDownloadFileA just got the main path without the parameters.

```
 URLDownloadToFile(NULL, "localhost:8080/test.php?", "username=" + UserNameBuffer, "&token=" TokentBuf, "C:\\", 0, NULL);
```

Comment: The query string should be part of the vallid URL passed to `URLDownloadToFile`. Perhaps double-check it's getting the string you expect and that the server isn't internally redirecting or stripping the parameters.

Comment: Please explain why you do not want to use libcurl. Maybe showing how you would do it with it and then explain the problem.

Comment: This is what I am trying URLDownloadToFile(NULL, "localhost:8080/test.php?", "username=" + UserNameBuffer, "&token=" TokentBuf, "C:\\", 0, NULL);
I also verified it only gets "localhost:8080/test.php?"

I do not wanna use libcurl cause including it never seems to work I get over 200  errors I have tried everything

Answer (score 0):

You need to build the full URL as a string before you pass it to the second argument of the function.

So something like this:

```
std::string url = "localhost:8080/test.php?username=";
url = url + UserNameBuffer + "&token=" + TokentBuf;
URLDownloadToFile(NULL, url.c_str() , "C:\\test.txt", 0, NULL);
```

The concept of HTTP parameters has nothing to do with the concept of function parameters for the URLDownloadToFile function.